# I'm trying to figure out the date of this puch moped

Tags: vintage

[image]

I'm trying to figure out the date of this puch moped its kick start [image]

Answer (score 3):

According to this [puch fanpage](http://puchfreunde.npage.at/technik/identifikationsnummern-v-mopeds.html) that MS50 got build somewhere between 17.09.1973 and 10.05.1974